# How can I remove the border of a textArea in extJs?

Tags: extjs, textarea, border, styling

I am new to extJs. I want to make the border of a textarea invisible so that it becomes just a blank white space (My purpose is to show it inside a fieldset).

Hoe can I achieve this?

thanks

Comment: style: 'border: none; background-image: none;'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the style: `border: none;`
so:

```
var textArea = {
fieldLabel: 'Test',
style: 'border: none;',
hideBorders: true
};
```

Comment: Thanks, now I am able to hide borders but it seems there is a shadow effect by default on the top. No idea how to remove that :(

Comment: @pencilCake add `background-image:none;` on fieldStyle